# Firebase notifications not recieving more than 4 devices connected to Airtel wifi hotspot. Is there any reason?

Tags: firebase, push-notification

Firebase notifications not recieving more than 4 devices connected to Airtel wifi hotspot. Is there any reason?. Please suggest me how to overcome this issue in Android & ios

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is in the background while sending notifications or you must handle the notifications manually in onMessageReceived() method in order to show notifications when your app is in the foreground.

Comment: Yes I am handling its working fine in all scenarios only this scenario Its failing